# line spacing in R/tikz figure annotation

Tags: r, tikz

I'm making a figure in R using the Tikz. I am adding text spanning two lines to the margins using mtext. How can I decrease the distance between the two lines of text generated by mtext?

Here is an example of the R script:

```
library("tikzDevice")
outfn<-"LineSpaceingExample.tex"
mydim <- 4
tikz(outfn,standAlone=TRUE,width=mydim,height=mydim)
mytext<- "This is some\nexample text"
x<-c(0, 1)
y<-x
plot(x, y, type = "n")
mtext(text=mytext, side=3,line=0.1)
dev.off()
```

The figure I get after compiling the .tex file generated by this script is: [image]

To clarify, I would like to contol the vertical distance between "This is some" and "example text".

Answer (score 0):

Another round of Googling turned up [a solution](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Line-spacing-in-graphics-td3313715.html): decreasing `par()$lheight` before calling `mtext`. 
The following script did the trick:

```
library("tikzDevice")
outfn<-"LineSpaceingExample.tex"
mydim<-4
tikz(outfn,standAlone=TRUE,width=mydim,height=mydim)
mytext1<- "This is the default\nline spacing"
mytext2<- "This is modified\nline spacing"
x<-c(0, 1)
y<-x
plot(x, y, type = "n")
mtext(text=mytext1, side=3,line=0.1, at=0.2)
par(lheight=0.8)
mtext(text=mytext2, side=3,line=0.1, at=0.8)
dev.off()
```

[image: Output plot]